# Calling out a single category using 'new WP_Query'

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, categories, args

I excluded a category in a loop (which worked great) and now I want to call out that same category in this loop below. (So that it will display at the bottom of the page.) I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes can help tell me what's going on here. It's not showing anything. I'm using a 'new WP_Query' to bring in the single category... here it is:

```
<?php // Begin Recent Sold loop of 3 ?>
<?php $args = new WP_Query('cat=367'); // category 367
    while($args->have_posts()) : $args->the_post(); ?>

<div class="category">
    <h2 class="artist-name">
        <?php echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a> <a class="viewall" href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID ) . '">VIEW ALL</a>'; ?></h2>

    <ul class="subcats">
    <?php
        $cats = wp_list_categories('orderby=name&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=0&depth=1&echo=0&show_count=1&child_of='.$category->cat_ID);
        if (!strpos($cats,'No categories') ){
        echo $cats;
        }
    ?>
    </ul>


    <div class="row clearfix">


    <?php $query = array(
        'post_type' => 'work',
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'orderby' => 'post_title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
            );
        query_posts($query);
    if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

        $rows = get_field('images');
        if(get_the_post_thumbnail()){

        echo '<div class="four column work"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'medium');
        echo '</a></div>';
        } else {

            if($rows)
                {
                foreach($rows as $row)
                    {
                    echo '<div class="four column work"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
                    echo '<img src="'. $row['image']['sizes']['medium'] . '" class="shadowed forced" alt="'.$row['image']['alt'].'">';
                    echo '</a></div>';
                    } ?>


                <?php }
            }
            ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .category -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

    <?php // End Recent Sold loop ?>
```

Comment: [Don't use `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) -- your best bet is probably to create a second `WP_Query` for your second loop.

Comment: @PatJ Thanks, so use a second WP_Query after the array instead of query_posts()?

Comment: Yeah, something like `$second = new WP_Query( $query );`. Also, you'll need to use `$second->have_posts()`, `$second->the_post()`, etc, in place of `have_posts()`, `the_post()`, etc, in your second loop.

Comment: Thanks @PatJ - but for some reason, that's not working either. This entire loop hasn't been talking with the site for some reason.

Comment: @PatJ - I figured it out- 
<?php   
 $args = array(
 'include'     => '367'
 );
 
 $categories = get_categories( $args );
 $parent_categories = '';
 foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?>

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -

I 'excluded' the Category ID in the array of the first loop to remove it, so in the second loop, I 'included' that same Category ID. Too simple... I though it'd include that ID along with the rest, thinking it'd be redundant. Anyway, thanks for the help!

```
<?php   
$args = array(
'include'   => '367'
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );
$parent_categories = '';
foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?>
```